# Oracle 11g XE to 18c XE - What is the difference? Is 18c can be used like 11g XE?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-18c

I have worked on Oracle 11g XE about two months ago. After that I de installed them about a week ago. Now, I am curious to learn a little bit more about databases and I tried to installed Oracle 11g XE since it is free.

When I tried today to [`install`](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index-092322.html), the site kept rerouting me to install Oracle 18c XE. Not sure why they force us to download "18c XE"?

In Oracle Site it says, they just released it 2 days ago. Is it okay to download and use like 11g XE? What are the differences between them?

(I can't find any solid evidence why I should use `18C`??)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Not sure why they force us to download `18c XE`?

They're not forcing you to download 18c XE.  They're just making it harder for you to download older versions

> Is it okay to download and use like 11g XE?

Yes.
I suggest you still read the [License Agreement for 18c XE](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/licenses/db18c-express-license-5137264.html).

> What are the differences between them?

Resource Limits have been increased (information can be found in License Agreement section License Rights)

- 2GB of RAM (up from 1)
- 12GB of user data (up from 11)
- 2 CPU Threads (I don't know if this is the same as 2 CPU cores.  11g was limited to 1 CPU core)

New database features

- The ability to handle [SCD Type 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension) data via Flashback Data Archive (11.2.0.4+)
- The ability to handle SCD Type 2 data via Temporal Validity (12c+)
- MATCH_RECOGNIZE (12c)
- other 12c features
- other 18c features

["more or less all EE Features"](https://mobiliardbblog.wordpress.com/2017/10/20/new-xe-version-available-with-oracle-18c/) (list from [18c XE Licensing Information](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/xelic/licensing-information.html#GUID-0F2574A6-360F-4237-8098-17B02FFC3BB3))

- EE feature Virtual Private Database (VPD)
- [Enterprise Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/xeinl/using-enterprise-manager-express.html) (missing in 11g XE)
- Java inside the database (missing in 11g XE)
- Partitioning (EE add-on)
- Multitenet (EE add-on - XE is limited to 3 PDBs)
- Advance Compression (EE add-on)
- In-Memory column store (EE add-on)
- Advanced Analytics (EE add-on)

  > (I can't find any solid evidence why I should use 18C??)

Because 11.2.0.2 (11g XE) is known to be buggy and full of security holes.

anti-upgrade reasons:  Minimum supported Oracle APEX version is [5.1.4](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/xeinl/exporting-and-importing-data-apex-users.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, they don't have an installer for windows yet! So, I have to go back to `11g R2 XE`

Comment: Be patient, young padawan.  They will release the Windows version.

Comment: If you are just want to practice SQL statements, you can try out http://LiveSQL.oracle.com