# How to run EM of Oracle 11g, if i haven't emctl, netmgr, dbca, OracleDBConsole<SID>?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-enterprise-manager

I don't know what is wrong with my Oracle 11g, but it is missing a lot of things. After reinstallation it stays the same. My overall path is like `C:\oraclexe\app\oracle` and after it there are folders like `admin`, `diag`, `fast_recovery_area`, `oradata`, `product`. Also, I don't have `dbca`, `netmgr`, `emctl` and service called `OracleDBConsole<SID>`. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with it, you installed 11g Express Edition, which is limited and does not include most features.

You can download other editions from here:

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html

Comment: 18c XE was released a few days ago.  Documentation seems to indicate that it comes with an express edition of EMCTL.  However, we're still waiting on the Windows release.

Comment: @MichaelKutz 12/18c has Enterprise Manager Database Express. 11g was the last version that had `emctl`, that controlled Enterprise Manager Database Console.

Comment: @AltynbekAmirzhanov -  XE is 11.2.0.2.  Check results of `SELECT * FROM V$VERSION` to verify.

Comment: @BalazsPapp - typo on my part.  If you see anything "major" missing from my list, feel free to edit/correct.  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/220730/oracle-11g-xe-to-18c-xe-what-is-the-difference-is-18c-can-be-used-like-11g-xe/220751?noredirect=1#comment433312_220751

Comment: @MichaelKutz, I'm sorry. You were right.